# Mail Compose View Controller Won't Open From UIAlertController

Tags: ios, uialertcontroller, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I am trying to pull up a Mail compose view controller after pushing a button from a UIAlertController.  In simulator, I get the normal crash and error message I always get in Simulator when trying to open mail, but in app, I get nothing.  No controller, no crash, nothing.  Here is the code.

```
[actionSheet addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Email" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {

        [self emailThem];

        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        }];
    }]];

-(void) emailThem {
    NSLog(@"EMAIL");
    MFMailComposeViewController *mail = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    mail.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [mail setSubject:@"To P3 Media"];
    [mail setMessageBody:@"Replace this text with your message for all the information you would like on P3 Media." isHTML:NO];
    [mail setToRecipients:@[@"p3media2014@gmail.com"]];

    [self presentViewController:mail animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Try putting "[self emailThem]" inside of the completion handler after dismissing the view controller. Also make sure presentViewController under the method emailThem is running on the user interface thread.

Comment: @SeanMcDonald Ok I tried that `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
            [self emailThem];
        }];` but still same thing.

Comment: Do you have an email account set up on the device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This Code

```
[actionSheet addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Email" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {

    [self emailThem];

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    }];
}]];

-(void) emailThem {
    NSLog(@"EMAIL");
    MFMailComposeViewController *mail = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    mail.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [mail setSubject:@"To P3 Media"];
    [mail setMessageBody:@"Replace this text with your message for all the information you would like on P3 Media." isHTML:NO];
    [mail setToRecipients:@[@"p3media2014@gmail.com"]];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
        [self presentViewController:mail animated:YES completion:NULL];
    });
}
```